# Can I request refund for an app that I purchased previously, but has now become free to download?

Tags: macos, ipad, ios-appstore

The reason that I would like to request a refund is not just that because it has become free to download.

The app (Splashtop Wired XDisplay), has stopped its support for latest the macOS version, which totally defeats its purpose, which is to allow me to use my iPad as a secondary display for my Mac.

Comment: The fuel I bought last week has since become cheaper - can I get a refund?

Comment: Hi there: I am not entirely sure if it would turn out to be successful but you can ask for a refund through the report-a-problem link on this [Apple support page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204084)

Comment: @SolarMike it's a different situation, i'm requesting refund as they do not provide support for the latest macos versin, which makes me feel cheated

Comment: But it worked when you bought it for the system you had then...

Answer (score 1):

You may or may not be eligible to get a refund. Only the relevant team at Apple can answer that for you.

Consider going through this Apple Support article first: [Request a refund for apps or content that you bought from Apple](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204084).

You should also consider contacting the customer support for the app to query if they have an update to the app in progress which will enable it to work on the recent/unsupported versions of macOS.

On the other hand, their app is still supported on older (prior to recent) releases of macOS and either some technical or business reason(s) may be preventing them from updating it to work with latest macOS.

Answer (score 0):

To contact Apple start at https://getsupport.apple.com/ and select Apps -> App Store.